# How to hide mat-expansion-panel in Angular?

Tags: angular

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SD1Pc.png)

I want to hide it when array  is empty

Comment: is there any code you can show it ?

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: <mat-expansion-panel  
      class="deployable-zone bloc-volet-detail"
      [expanded]="true"
      *ngIf="detailsDeclaration.adhesionsPremiereEmbauches?.length> 0"
    >
      <mat-expansion-panel-header  
        [expandedHeight]="'30px'"
        [collapsedHeight]="'30px'"

Comment: @Anderson what do you want to hide ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this declaratively by setting the value of input `expanded` to `false` if some condition is met, or imperatively by calling method `toggle` on your `MatExpansionPanel` ViewChild from your component. See [angular-material docs](https://material.angular.io/components/expansion/api#MatExpansionPanel).

```html
<mat-expansion-panel [expanded]="isExpanded ? true : false">
  <other stuff/>
</mat-expansion-panel>
```

**EDIT**: I suppose you could *ngIf the entire `mat-expansion-panel` component as well, but it'll likely be less efficient because that would imply the entire panel gets rerendered in the DOM whenever its expanded state precondition changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [hidden]="*clause*" like this:

```
  <mat-expansion-panel [hidden]="true">
     ...
  </mat-expansion-panel>
```